# Problem with “Trust anchor for certification path not found.”

Tags: java, android, spring, retrofit2, okhttp

Hello i didn't found solution for my problem. In new OkHttp and Retrofit is some function:

```
 HandshakeCertificates certificates =  new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
                        .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
                        .addInsecureHost("192.168.0.150")
                        .build();
```

I am trying to connect my Android App to Spring Boot Server. This Server must use HTTPS - not my idea.
On this server i generated self-sign certyficate, but still i got error, now i don't have any ideas. Here is a full error:
`java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`
Below i insert code of Retrofit generator:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://192.168.0.150:8443/";
    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    // private static OkHttpClient httpClient = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return createService(serviceClass, null);
    }

    static public <S> S createService(
            Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor =
                    new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);

            if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
                httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

                HandshakeCertificates certificates =  new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
                        .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
                        .addInsecureHost("192.168.0.150")
                        .build();
                httpClient.sslSocketFactory(certificates.sslSocketFactory(), certificates.trustManager());

                OkHttpClient okHttpClient = httpClient.build();

                builder.client(okHttpClient);
                retrofit = builder.build();
            }
        }

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Request Code:

```
 private void doLoginRequest() {
        DeviceAPI deviceAPI = ServiceGenerator.createService(DeviceAPI.class);
        Call<JWTResponse> call = deviceAPI.login(new Login(usernameEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString()));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JWTResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JWTResponse> call, Response<JWTResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JWTResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.getCause());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, t.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Api Code:

```
public interface DeviceAPI {
    @POST("api/auth/signin")
    Call<JWTResponse> login(@Body Login login);
}
```

If you need more information give me feedback!

Comment: First of all the config of the okhttpclient should be independently (should not be done in the if conditions). And if your server uses SSL (which should always be the case) you should validate the certificate. You can add the servercertificate (Public Key) directly (see https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java). The whole retrofit config should be done in the constructor of your class. I guess the authtoken is always the same or null? The interceptors contains check should not be required as well if you do this in the constructor

Comment: I have JWT Token on server-side, I was trying add to android app genereted public key - but still no changes - still same error, and doesn't work ignore all certyficates.

Comment: You can try this approach https://gist.github.com/demixdn/3886de5a71dc2812c8f4d27a248a506b Hint: Best way would be to use the root or intermediate certificate for the validation (they do not expire that fast = you don't need to update the cert file in your clients that often)

Comment: As a stackoverflow example - this isn't really useful for others to help you.  You should extract a working example that would run with minimal dependencies.  It's mostly guess work from the example you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

This example shows connecting twice to a host - Once with a valid HTTPS Handshake, and second using addInsecureHost.  n.b. you won't get a handshake peer in the second because the handshake won't result in valid certificates.

The same will apply if you run against a dev server, so edit the example to use your devserver.

https://gist.github.com/yschimke/796e58a6152137bdcd7d2f9d63e26363

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.tls.HandshakeCertificates.Builder

fun main() {
  val request = Request.Builder()
      .url("https://httpbin.org/get")
      .build()

  var client = OkHttpClient();
  var response = client.newCall(request).execute()

  println(response.handshake?.peerPrincipal) // CN=httpbin.org
  println(response.code)

  val certificates = Builder()
      .addInsecureHost("httpbin.org")
      .build()

  client = OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(certificates.sslSocketFactory(),
      certificates.trustManager
  ).build();
  response = client.newCall(request).execute()

  println(response.handshake?.peerPrincipal) // null
  println(response.code)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but when I trying and giving my IP address to this example I still get that handshake error.